# Check password of large 7zip file quickly

Tags: encryption, 7-zip, password-recovery

I have a large 7zip file which I forgot the password to. 
I can narrow down the password possibilities to a word list with about 2000 passwords. 
Only problem is, that it takes ages for each password to be checked, since its such a large file.
Is there a way to speed up the process, or is a 7zip file encrypted as "one"? 
I am a complete noob in this field, thats why I am asking.

Comment: How long is 'ages'? 1 minute? That means, worst case, you crack the PW in a bit less than 1 and a half days. How imprortant is this data?

Comment: Its not that important, I was just curious if someone could point me somewhere, since I was not able to find anything on this

Comment: Though there might be a "hacking" app out there, you might consider writing two scripts: one to create a text file with all the permutations of the password, e.g., *MyPassword*, *myPassword*, *mypassword*, *MyPassw0rd*... and another script to open 7Zip, iterating through the file and password list.

Answer (score 0):

Use the commandline interface of 7z to test the archive. As a parameter you can pass a password. You can wrap this in a scripting for-loop that loops over your candidate passwords.

- [Commandline options of 7z](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm)
- You can use [the exitcode](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/exit_codes.htm) to check if you got the right password.

The 7z command is thus: `7z t archive.zip -p <password>`

In pseudocode:

```
FOR password IN passwordlist:
    exitcode = 7z t archive.zip -p password
    IF exitcode == 0:
        PRINT Found password: password
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that later. Does this solve the issue I have described above?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't "solve" my question. It does jsut take as long

Comment: How about the l (list) command instead of t(esting) the file?

Comment: That does not check for the password I believe?

Comment: But actually you helped me to a certain degree, "t" is 1.75 as fast as "x". So thansk for that, I believe I will just brute force it now, since I don"t believe it can become any faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a command line tool called johntheripper to crack passwords, it is used to crack os passwords but you can also provide it a 7z file using another utility called 7z2john.